# How far can pixie see unaided?

Tags: biology, fantasy-races, mythical-creatures, vision

Flash news: A mysterious creature very much resembles a pixie was killed in a freak accident involving a sparrow, authority suspects no foul play since interviews with the local mythology creatures expert suggested pixie are shortsighted and this little one could have collided with a high velocity sparrow...

I smelled something fishy is going on and refused to accept the authority explanation especially since there are too many plot holes in the stories... like is the pixie really short sighted? Some animals such as a certain specie of eagles which are much smaller than us proportionately in term of body size but can see a tiny object from miles away, so ideally can a ping pong ball sized pixie achieve similar feats or just as the claims had suggested they really are shortsighted?

Comment: How do you expect us to answer since you are giving 0 information on these pixies?

Comment: An accident with a Sparrow and no fowl play suspected? ;) Seriously though, your pixies are flying types, right? There is no believable reason for any flying creature to be shortsighted. A tiny eyeball will reduce the maximum resolution, thus small objects at great distances will not be discernable, but that is totally different from having focus problems.

Comment: Since you haven't provided any details about the size of your pixies, maybe you could research existing creatures the same size you want your pixies to be. Just a wild example, the saying goes one can have the eyes of the hawk while somebody else could be as blind as a bat...

Comment: @Argent Hellion  Bats are not usually "blind as a bat".  Though many bat species do have poor vision, all bat species can see, and some bat species have good vision.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat#Vision

Comment: Flying Birds as a whole tend to have pretty decent vision, because that's the main sense they use to orient themselves while flying. Bats are a little different, since while some species use their vision exclusively, others also rely on echolocation, but overall all have at least somewhat decent vision. Is your pixie more closely related to mammals or birds? Maybe something else like insects? What size are they? What's their main sense for navigation? This question's answer right now is really whatever guess that sounds the most fitting to you , which is a problem according to the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

So, your question is somewhat vague since you don't provide much information on said pixies. BUT, I found some information on different animals in the animal kingdom.

As you mentioned, eagles do have good vision. As for small creatures, the first resource below talks about mantis shrimp, which have some of the most complex eyes in the world. When considering vision complexity, you'll want to take into account what cones and rods the eyes have and what the animals perceive. For example, some animals can see infrared light, unlike humans (like snakes, they see infrared). Other animals, like goats and sheep, have differently shaped pupils.

https://allabouteyes.com/best-eyes-animal-kingdom/

So taking this into account, and since it is a mythical creature, creative and scientific ideas can come together. You can take into account the time of day (are they a nighttime creature? How do their pupils affect their vision?), you can take into account light and what waves they see (maybe the pixie cannot see the wavelength that allows the sparrow to be seen?). Additionally taking in other perceptions such as sound may help (like echolocation).

In the end, it really is up to your own artistic and creative choice. But these are some options to consider.

Here's a source that compares human vision to a variety of animals with some visuals: https://www.eyesite.co.uk/news/humans-vs-animals-who-has-better-vision/